# Help with Apache mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to change some legacy URL's like this:

```
/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=600
```

to this:

```
/news/story/600/
```

This is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=News&file=([a-z_]+)&sid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^modules\.php /news/story/%2/ [R=301,L]
```

However I still get 404's on the old URLs.

I do have some other rewrite rules working, so I am pretty sure mod_rewrite is enabled and functioning. These rules are in a httpd.conf file in a VirtualHost container.

I should also mention this is for a Python application (using Django) running with mod_wsgi. Should the rewrites happen before the URLs are passed to the wsgi application?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. It seems I had a couple of problems.

1. I needed a forward slash on the pattern in RewriteRule; i.e.
   `^/modules.php` instead of
   `^modules.php`.
2. I needed to prevent the query string from being appended to the new URL. This could cause recursion in some cases, or other strange things (400 bad request). A trailing `?` did the trick.

I ended up with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/modules\.php /news/story/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are these "other rewrite rules" located? In the same .conf or .htaccess file? I think you need `Options +FollowSymlinks` on the line just above `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: The working rewrite rules are right next to the ones that don't work, in a .conf file. They are in a VirtualHost container.

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned about `Options +FollowSymlinks`?

You could try putting the rewrite-rules in a .htaccess file.

Comment: I did try the Options + FollowSymlinks, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not using a .htaccess file; this is for a Python / WSGI application where the URL's don't really map to a directory (at least that is my understanding). But I don't know what I'm doing for sure. :)

Comment: `FollowSymLinks` is not actually required when mod_rewrite is used directly in the server config / VirtualHost.